# security login check in php not authenticating

Tags: php, mysql

security login check in php not authenticating. I am rewriting this mysql deprecated code to PDO but before then, I need to sort out one issue.

This code was used for login authentication by passing a username and password via a form inputs.Now i also wants to 
add another inputs like security Code as per code below

```
$sql=mysql_query("select * from members where security='$sec'");
if($row=mysql_num_rows($sql)==0){
    echo "<font color=red>Security Code is incorrect</font>";
}
```

The problem is that security code check is skipped during authentication. I think the problem might be from
my if statement. Any help will be appreciated.

```
<?php

include("db_deprecated.php");

$uname=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["uname"]);
$pass=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["pass"]);
$sec=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["sec"]);



$sql=mysql_query("select * from members where username='$uname'");
if($row=mysql_num_rows($sql)==0){
    echo "<font color=red>The Username is incorrect</font>";
}else{

$sql=mysql_query("select * from members where password='$pass'");
if($row=mysql_num_rows($sql)==0){
    echo "<font color=red>The Password is in correct</font>";

}else{

$sql=mysql_query("select * from members where usernameu='$uname' and password='$pass'");
$row=mysql_fetch_array($sql);

//print login successful

}

}

?>
```

Comment: **WARNING**: This code is violating a number of security rules like employing plain-text passwords and using the obsolete `mysql_query interface. Please, do not try and write your own security layer when a 
[development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) comes with a robust [authentication system](http://laravel.com/docs/security) out of the box.

Comment: so it looks like you are not storing hashes or encrypted passwords, problem #1,  Problem 2. is that your current code reveals too much info to a would be attacker,(Weather username is valid or not, and weather any password in the system matches the inputed one).  You should just do something like  your last  query, see if it returns any row, else fail with incorrect username/password.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are missing out the brackets in the right place.

All the `if` statements should be something like this, `if(($row=mysql_num_rows($sql))==0)`

Comment: Thanks resolved. the problem is that i forgot to initialized the form variables of the email on the ajax form

Comment: Thanks, the correction is not from php part, its from the ajax form making the request. As for rating, all advice given are excellent

Answer (score 0):

Your if statements are returning the boolean value of the == operator to the $row variable.

I usually read those kind of expressions from right to left.

So the first thing that is processed is:

```
mysql_num_rows($sql)==0
```

The operator == will return either true or false.

Then, the result returned by the == operator will be assigned to your variable $row.

As suggested in another answer, in order to avoid this you should encapsulate your assignment:

```
if (($row = mysql_num_rows($sql))==0)
```

Be aware that your code shouldn't be used in production environments as it contains lots of security issues.

Comment: This code is just for testing purposes. thanks everyone

Comment: You're welcome. Please select any of the answers as correct if you're happy with them, I guess we all need reputation in here :D.